# Extending postgresql code

Tags: development, postgresql, eclipse-cdt, functions

In postgresql source code there is a file called `postgres.c` precisely in `/src/backend/tcop/`. Inside there is a function called `exec_simple_query`.
I want add a line that call `my_function` that is in another file called `test.c` in the same folder of postgres.c .

I'm working with eclipse on linux (kubuntu/ubuntu). I followed this tutorial to creating the environment http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Eclipse

This is test.c:

```
#include "postgres.h"

#ifndef PROGPROFILE_H_
#define PROGPROFILE_H_

/* interfaces */
extern void start_create_profile(List *querytree_list);
extern void create_profile();
extern void check_anomaly(List *querytree_list);

#endif /* Test ProgProf */


void start_create_profile(List *querytree_list){

    ListCell *l;
    ListCell *tl;
    FILE *f;

    //if the file exist just open and write
    //else create and write
    f = fopen ("QueryParsed.txt", "a+");

    Query *query_idr = (Query *)linitial(querytree_list);

    // CMD_SELECT=0 CMD_INSERT=1 CMD_UPDATE=2
    switch (query_idr->commandType)
    {
        case CMD_SELECT:
            fputs("CMD_SELECT, ", f);
        break;

        case CMD_INSERT:
            fputs("CMD_INSERT, ", f);
            break;

        case CMD_UPDATE:
            fputs("CMD_UPDATE, ", f);
        break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    //to have the ID of the table
    foreach(l, query_idr->rtable){
        Oid tab_idT = ((RangeTblEntry *) lfirst(l)) ->relid;
        //char temp1[10];
        char *tab_idTConverted = itoa(tab_idT);
        /* This is not a table */
        if (tab_idT == 0)
            continue;

        fputs(" tab_id:  , ", f);
        fputs(tab_idTConverted, f);

    }

    //to have the name of the targer list
    foreach(tl, query_idr->targetList){
        TargetEntry *tle = (TargetEntry *) lfirst(tl);
        Oid tab_id = tle->resorigtbl;
        int tab_idCast=(int)tab_id;
        //char temp[10];
        char *tab_idConverted = itoa(tab_idCast);
        char *resname=tle->resname;

        fputs("Name of column:  ", f);
        fputs(resname, f);
        fputs(" ID:  ", f);
        fputs(tab_idConverted, f);
        fputs("\n", f);
    }

    //close the file that we write
    fputs("$", f);
    fclose (f);
}


void create_profile(){

}

void check_anomaly(List *querytree_list){

}
```

But, when I click on `build` I get this error:

```
Description Path    Resource    Location    Type
make: *** [all] Error 2     pgsql       C/C++ Problem
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2      pgsql       C/C++ Problem
make[2]: *** [postgres] Error 1     pgsql       C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `start_create_profile'   /pgsql/src/backend/tcop postgres.c      C/C++ Problem
```

I don't think that is related to postgresql, but I think it is a problem of extension programming.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem adding `test.o` in OBJECT in the `makefile` in `src/backend/tcop`.

An istance can be

```
subdir = src/backend/tcop
top_builddir = ../../..
include $(top_builddir)/src/Makefile.global

OBJS= dest.o fastpath.o postgres.o pquery.o utility.o test.o

ifneq (,$(filter $(PORTNAME),cygwin win32))
override CPPFLAGS += -DWIN32_STACK_RLIMIT=$(WIN32_STACK_RLIMIT)
endif

include $(top_srcdir)/src/backend/common.mk
```